# unit test to make sure my view does not crash

Tags: unit-testing, c#-4.0, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm new to unit testing so this may be a daft question.

Usinf mvc 4 I have a view which was working fine.

I declared my model at the top and all was fine.

I then extracted my models out into a seperate library and forgot to change the model declaration on one of my views, hence is crashes.

Is there a way to unit test this?

I don't want to do it by the page title of the view as this may change dynamically...

How is this handled normally or is this something not normally tested?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a series of tests I run against each View Model, including a test to make sure the expected property names are there. Here is an example:

```
/// <summary>
/// Check expected properties exist.
/// </summary>
[Test]
public void Check_Expected_Properties_Exist()
{

  // Get properties.
  PropertyInfo propInfoFirstName = typeof(ViewModels.MyModel).GetProperty("FirstName");
  PropertyInfo propInfoLastName = typeof(ViewModels.MyModel).GetProperty("LastName");

  // Assert.
  Assert.IsNotNull(propInfoFirstName);
  Assert.IsNotNull(propInfoLastName);

}
```

This is just one of a number of test I run, I will write a blog article on this topic and update this answer when it's ready.

I have added another Answer, in case the previous answer is helpful to anyone else.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Selnium WebDriver](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/projects/webdriver/) or [WatiN](http://watin.org/). There are plenty of tutorials and how-tos to get you started.

Answer (score 0):

I usually add a very simple test for each method in my controller to check it return a valid ActionResult.

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestMyController()
{
  // Arrange.
  var controller = new MyController();

  // Act.
  var result = controller.MyMethod() as ViewResult;

  // Assert.
  Assert.IsNotNull(result);
}
```

I also add a few tests for each View Model, as I have had an issue with these when they were in a separate class library, but this is outside the scope of your question.

Comment: But if the view is crashing, that wouldnt fail this test would it?

Comment: Simon, Can you tell me what you mean by 'the view crashing'? Do you mean the Controller cannot see the view (you've moved it to another library) or if there's a problem in the view model code.?

Comment: Yeah sorry I meant a problem in the view itself. So say for instance had @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Supplier.Name) but changed the property name to Firstname in my model but forgot to change it in the view...